# vertical scroll bar having expandable list view inside in android

Tags: android, xml, mobile

am developing an application in android. Am adding a vertical scroll bar around linear layout.The problem is that only half screen of the layout is visible. I want that scroll view should cover full screen. Here is my full screen layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="#4ba9d1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_icon" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="#242424"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="#363636"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/head_title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:fontFamily="@string/fonts"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="AssetTrac - Experience Zone"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
   </LinearLayout> 
   <ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical" >   
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:orientation="vertical" >     
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="#4ba9d1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@drawable/separ"
        >

    </ExpandableListView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="#4ba9d1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/signature"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="20"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/save_sig"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="94dp"
                android:text="Button" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/update_status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="94dp"
                android:text="Button" />


 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView> 
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would me much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollView parent's (LinearLayout with background "#242424") height is set to wrap_content. Therefore scrollview height which is fill_parent would have height of content size. 
Either set the scrollview parent's height as fill_parent or take out the scrollview outside the immediate linear layout tag.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    <!-- Layout Height set to fill_parent -->
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="#242424"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="#363636"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/head_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fontFamily="@string/fonts"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="AssetTrac - Experience Zone"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
      </LinearLayout> 

      <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:scrollbars="vertical" >  
      .......
```

Comment: thanks Ashish!. Now display is covering full but now scroll is not working :(

Comment: with your correction i've also added android:fillViewport="true" inside scrollview to get full screen but now scroll is not working.

Comment: You can't simply put one vertical scrolling item in another scrolling view. ExpandableListview is recognising the gesture and scrollview can't catch that gesture anymore. It's a known issue, find solution at another [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13796159/1779642).
Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:fillViewport="true"` in your `ScrollView` tag and it will fill whole screen

Comment: with your correction i've also edited scroll view's parent layout hight to fill parent to get full screen display.Now full screen display is available but now scroll is not working.

Comment: Are any views invisible?

Comment: Then how would it scroll? `ScrollView` only works when there are views that can not be fitted  in the screen.